# how to use grub to bypass a 32bit uefi to boot windows 10 x64

Tags: boot, 64-bit, grub, uefi

I have read in [another post](https://superuser.com/questions/883915/cant-boot-a-64bit-windows-usb-from-a-tablet-originally-installed-with-32-bit-os) that it is possible to boot an x64 copy of Windows 10 on a 32bit UEFI using GRUB. the hardware I am using fully supports a x64bit OS.  However, the UEFI is locked to 32bit and the manufacturer has no interest in updating the BIOS to support the 64bit UEFI. Can someone help me out with the steps?

Comment: it would be helpful if you quoted and linked to what you read.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK grub cannot do it. It can boot 64-bit Linux on 32-bit UEFI platform, but not Windows, since it is only capable of chainloading the EFI binary of Windows, and you can't chainload a 64-bit EFI binary with 32-bit grub EFI.

There might be something else that is capable of doing it in some way, though personally I haven't really heard of a concrete way.

Comment: This is my understanding, too.

Comment: can't you use 32-bit grub to chainload 64-bit grub then chainload 64-bit Windows bootloader?